# Making Adjacency Matrix from Geojson Files

Tags: image-processing, computational-geometry, geography, geographics, json-format

I modified by taking out the Earth's boundary and organized geojson files from [Geoboundaries](https://www.geoboundaries.org/) and put it [here](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1zJWvJCWOadys2o5zAH3QYBxrAGzfXkb9?usp=drive_link). Each subregion has the name of that region in it.

I want to make an adjacency matrix for the world/each country at a specified administrative level by reading the information from the Geojson. But because these are regions that have discrete points for boundaries, and some regions have islands that are disconnected, it is not straightforward to me how to find know which regions are touching and how they are touching.

Here are examples of different administrative levels for Myanmar:

[image: This is administrative level 1 for Myanmar. It is next coarsest after the main country.]

[image: This is administrative level 2 for Myanmar.]

[image: This is administrative level 3 for Myanmar. It is the finest map with many small boundaries.]

Here is the adjacency matrix with naming columns for Myanmar at the first (not zeroth) administrative level:

[image: Myanmar Provincial Relations Table]

produced by the code:

```
   MyanmarProvinceRelations =
{"Kachin"<->"Sagaing","Kachin"<->"Shan","Sagaing"<->"Shan","Sagaing"<->"Manadalay","Magway"<->"Manadalay","Magway"<->"Bago",
"Sagaing"<->"Magway","Sagaing"<->"Chin","Shan"<->"Kayah","Shan"<->"Mandalay",
"Shan"<->"Kayin","Kayin"<->"Bago","Kayin"<->"Mon","Mon"<->"Tanintharyi","Bago"<->"Yangon",
"Yangon"<->"Ayeyarwady","Bago"<->"Ayeyarwady","Magway"<->"Rakhine","Rakhine"<->"Chin","Magway"<->"Chin"};
    g = Graph[MyanmarProvinceRelations];
    am = AdjacencyMatrix[g]; 
    (* Get the ordered list of vertex names *)
    vertices = VertexList[g];
    (* Display the adjacency matrix with table headings *)
    TableForm[am, TableHeadings -> {vertices, vertices}]
```

I might have missed some relationships. It is difficult to keep track of manually.